# Finding files with certain permissions

Tags: linux, shell, command

I need to find all files in the current directory that cannot be written on by the user but can have any other permissions.

I'm trying to use
`find . -type f -perm -u=r+x` but it's not working properly.
I need to display files that only the user is unable to write on.
I don't understand why my code is not working.

Comment: It works fine over here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work :

```
find . -type f ! -writable
```

Or if you wanna use `-perm` instead use this:

```
find . -type -f ! -perm -u=w
```

the negation operaror is anyways helpfull.

Comment: Omg it works! but I was just wondering does this make sure that files with group/other write permissions will be displayed?

Comment: the ```-writable``` clause only applies to the user?

Comment: Yes the `writable` wil apply only to the user who run the process.

Comment: from man (1) find : "Matches file s which are writable by  the current user"

Comment: this displays the whole path of the file and by that I mean it shows the directory and filename too. What if I just wanted to display the filename?

Comment: add this to the end: `-printf "%f\n"`